# Why TryGetValue deallocates my Dictionary ?

Tags: c#, dictionary, trygetvalue

I have this piece of code :

```
Dictionary<string, object> tempDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

if(xDicionary.TryGetValue(...., out tempDict)
{
tempDict.Add(...);
}
else
{
tempDict.Add(..);
}
```

If the code passes to the else block then I got and exception that cannot perform add because tempDict points to null. Why is this happening ? I know how to bypass it in an ugly way by allocating new Dictionary also in the else block but is there any better way of doing this ?

Comment: By design.  TryGetValue() failed so tempDict is null.  Rethink your logic.

Comment: It doesn't deallocate, though it sest the `out` parameter to `null`.

Comment: You wouldn't want this design anyway. You only want to instantiate the new dictionary after you discover there is none, i.e. in the else clause, otherwise you're only wasting resources whenever there actually is already one in the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because methods that have an `out` parameter, **must** assign a value to the `out` parameter. That means that when you call `xDicionary.TryGetValue` `tempDict` is always overwritten, and when nothing is found, it is set to null. Therefore, in your else, `tempDict` will ***always*** be null.

Answer (score 1):

That's how `TryGetValue` works because it uses an `out` parameter. An `out` parameter is always assigned a value in a method and so whatever you initialise the parameter to, it will be overwritten.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) makes this point by stating:

> This parameter is passed uninitialized.

So you have to use a temporary.

Answer (score 1):

`TryGetValue` will return false and set the `tempDict` to `null` if it could not get the value.

This happens because an `out` parameter **must be definitely assigned** in the method being called, and when a value *can't* be retried for a value type, `null` is the **logical default** to assign to it.

This is the normal semantics of all BCL `TryGet*` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Because if `xDictionary` does not contain the value requested, `TryGetValue` returns `false` and the `out` value is set to `null`. Hence, when you try do `Add` something to `null` you get `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

You should put tempDict = new ... within the else {} block. If TryGetValue returns false then you cannot rely on the value in the out parameter.